# How to use gcc to generate 64bit exes in Windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin

I am using Babun (Cygwin + some useful added program + configs) in Windows 7 64 bit. I tried using gcc to compile C code (Take hello_world.c as an example) and it compiled (to an exe), but when I am trying to run the compiled program it shows an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"

A little research shows that it means that the compiled program is trying to call to 32 bit libraries. My question is: How do I set gcc (or what commands do I use while using gcc) to make the program use 64bit libraries by default and run properly?

The program to be compiled is a simple command line Hello World C program and I am trying to run the exe in cmd (which normally works when doing it using Codeblocks, but not in this case).

Comment: Babun (at the moment) does not support 64 bit configurations. [See this link.](https://github.com/babun/babun/wiki/64-bit) You can attempt to hack it but they don't recommend it.